# Why does my code repeat its values so many times?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a piece of code that shows you all the possible combinations to get a dollar. So 4 quarters, 3 quarters 25 pennies etc. I haven't tried actually inputting a dollar yet, since the code takes a very long time to run, but even when I input small amounts such as 30, it shows over 10 thousand results. This is because it repeats combinations like [10, 10, 10,] thousands of times. I am not sure why. Code is down below. Please help me out.

```
def change(n, coins_available, coins_so_far):
  if sum(coins_so_far) == n:
    yield coins_so_far
  elif sum(coins_so_far) > n:
    pass
  elif coins_available == []:
    pass
  else:
    for c in change(n, coins_available[:], coins_so_far+[coins_available[0]]):
      yield c
      for c in change(n, coins_available [1:], coins_so_far):
        yield c
n = 30
coins = [1, 5, 10, 25, 100]

solutions = [s for s in change(n, coins, [])]
for s in solutions:
  print(s)
```

Comment: Un-nest your loops. You want to consider the two options ("include this coin" vs "don't") separately. Right now you're saying "for every possible situation where we include this coin AND every possible one where we don't, yield values".

Comment: @SilvioMayolo do you also happen to know why the 25 value never shows up?

Comment: Perhaps adding some comment lines to your code, explaining what each line does, or is expected to do, might clarify what's going on to the reader, and yourself.

Comment: There's no need to copy the list with `coins_available[:]`. The function never modifies `coins_available`.

Answer (score 0):

Commenters have pointed out a few issues with the code from the question which prevents OP's function from returning the desired output.  Here is a 'fixed' version that produces correct output: refer to the comments in the code for a detailed breakdown of how it works.

Although it is (to the best of my knowledge) complete and correct, the code below still has one major issue - the list of all solutions it returns is bloated with redundant answers where only the ordering of the coin values within the nested lists is different.

This means that, for example, when you call the function for input value `10`, you will get `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5]`, `[1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1]`, `[1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1]` etc.  The desired result would most likely include any one of those equivalent results, but not all of them, in the list of possible solutions.

To show how the unwanted repetition can be eliminated, I have included both the original version and a 'patched' version underneath it.

ORIGINAL:

```
# Input:  a monetary amount, in cents (for $1, should use 100)
# Output:  a list of all lists of coin values adding up to the input amount
def getChange(forAmountInCents):
    # Check for invalid user input, like fractional cents or strings 
    if type(forAmountInCents) != int:
        print("Invalid Input")
        return
    
    # Cent values for all current US coins:  penny, nickel, dime and quarter
    coins = [1, 5, 10, 25]
    # This will be returned after it's populated with all valid combinations
    allCombinations = []

    # Helper function to populate allCombinations
    def constructSolution(listOfCoins):
        # Try adding every possible coin to the partial solution
        for c in coins:
            # New value of the partial solution if coin c should be added to it
            # NOTE:  Don't actually perform the addition yet!  We still need the
            # partial solution as it currently stands.
            currentValue = sum(listOfCoins) + c
            # If the partial solution with c added adds up to the target value
            # exactly, append to the list of all combinations.
            if currentValue == forAmountInCents:
                allCombinations.append(listOfCoins + [c])
            # If the partial solution is still too small, repeat all of the above
            elif currentValue < forAmountInCents:
                constructSolution(listOfCoins + [c])
            # If the partial solution with the new coin added is too big, just
            # do nothing (i.e. return)

    # Begin constructing each potential solution, starting with an empty list
    constructSolution([])

    # When the recursive helper function stops running, allCombinations will be
    # populated with all possible lists of coins adding up to the target value.
    return allCombinations

# Display all possible combinations of coins adding up to 10 cents.
# Note how many redundant solutions there are (same coins, different order)!
print(getChange(10))
```

EQUIVALENT FUNCTION WITH REDUNDANT SOLUTIONS REMOVED:

```
def getChange(forAmountInCents):
    if type(forAmountInCents) != int:
        print("Invalid Input")
        return
    
    coins = [1, 5, 10, 25]
    allUniqueCombinations = []

    # Now, instead of constructing lists, use dictionaries to keep track of the number of each coin
    # in the solutions being constructed. This removes the dependence on index position, which was
    # what was causing the redundant solutions in the original version.
    def constructSolution(dictOfCoins):
        for c in coins:
            # Make a deep copy of dictOfCoins, and increment the count for the relevant coin in that copy
            testSolution = {1: dictOfCoins[1], 5: dictOfCoins[5], 10: dictOfCoins[10], 25: dictOfCoins[25]}
            testSolution[c] += 1
            # The product of the number of each coin and that coin's value gives the total value so far
            currentValue = sum([k*testSolution[k] for k in testSolution])
            # Before appending a (correct) solution, check whether there is already an equivalent one
            # in the list.  Only append the current one if it is not already in the list.
            if (currentValue == forAmountInCents) and (testSolution not in allUniqueCombinations):
                allUniqueCombinations.append(testSolution)
            elif currentValue < forAmountInCents:
                constructSolution(testSolution)
            
    constructSolution({1: 0, 5: 0, 10: 0, 25: 0})

    # Now that the list has been populated with all correct and unique solutions, convert them from
    # dicts back to lists, to keep this function's output equivalent to the first version's.
    all_as_lists = []
    for solution in allUniqueCombinations:
        newList = []
        for k in solution:
            for i in range(solution[k]):
                newList.append(k)
        all_as_lists.append(newList)
            
    return all_as_lists

# Now, only unique combinations will be shown. 
print(getChange(10))
```

Running the improved version for input `25` gives the following result:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 10], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 10], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 10], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 10], [5, 10, 10], [25]]
```

Unfortunately, these functions are still prohibitively slow for larger inputs (including 1 dollar, or `100` cents).  This is inherent in the O(n!) time complexity of any procedure which attempts to find all given permutations (as in the first example) or combinations (as in the improved example*) of a given set of items.

*Note that although the improved version only **outputs** unique *combinations*, it must still evaluate all possible *permutations* in order to arrive at that filtered set.

It is very likely possible to write a more efficient function that gives the same result using *dynamic programming*, but that's not really my area.  Hopefully other users take this as a challenge and post their own answers with dynamic solutions :D